# what does mean t in t.column_name in pod framework?

Tags: php, wordpress, frameworks

I am learning Pod framework(Version 1.14.7 this really bad because it is an old version) in WordPress. I can see in my code example that there is using some kind of codes that have `t.business_approved`. But I am wondering what does mean by `t` here. My codes are below.

```
$businesses = new Pod('businesses');
codesearch3 = "AND t.address_city = '$mycitycookie'";
$query_where = "(t.business_approved = '1' AND business_tab_1_content !='' $codesearch3)";
$businesses->findRecords('Order By statement', 3,$query_where);
```

I tried some googling and get to know that here **businesses** is pod name and **address_city** and **business_approved** are the column names for the pod.

But I can not understand what is doing `t` before `business_approved`. 
Would anyone please give me some information that can help me out to understand about `t` in pod framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that appears to be an SQL query, and 't' would either be the name of, or an alias to, the table you are doing a query on.

Comment: That means here  `t` can be equal to the table name of Pod. I mean `t = businesses`. Is that?

Comment: It would appear that is correct, businesses would be the table, which is aliased as 't', so you can use t.column_name to reference columns to lookup on.